# How to show passed test in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-node

When running `jasmine` it only presents dot(`.`) for successful tests, and only verbose if the test fails.

```
//test.spec.js
describe('jasmine', ()=>{
  it('should show this text', () =>{
  });
})
```

My running command is: `jasmine-node test.spec.js`

The result:

```
.
Finished in 0.003 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

How to make `jasmine` display this test result like `jasmine should show this text`?

Comment: If it helps your search, you're asking how to configure or use a different **reporter** with jasmine.

Comment: I realise that this does not answer your question directly, but [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) does list passing tests for you, it maybe an alternative for you to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`--verbose`](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) flag:

```
> jasmine-node test.spec.js --verbose

jasmine - 0 ms
    should show this test - 0 ms

Finished in 0.007 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

---

Note: `jasmine-node` doesn't seem to be actively maintained. The [`jasmine` CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine) supports tests run from the command line.

Although `jasmine` doesn't have a verbose flag, you can use a custom terminal reporter (example: `jasmine-terminal-reporter`). From [jasmine's documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/node.html#section-9), add a helper file to load the custom reporter and include the helper in your configuration file.

**helpers/terminal-reporter.js**

```
var Reporter = require('jasmine-terminal-reporter');
var reporter = new Reporter(options);

jasmine.addReporter(reporter);
```

**spec/support/jasmine.json**

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js",
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: false,
  random: false
}
```

Comment: `--verbose` works for `jasmine-node` but not `jasmine`. Any solution for `jasmine`?

Comment: edited my answer to include a solution for `jasmine`, it allows setup of custom reporters.

Comment: thank you for you answer. In jasmine docs, there is `var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var jasmine = new Jasmine();`. Do you know where should I place these lines of code. `jasmine init` only creates `spec/support/jasmine.json`. There is not any `.js` file to put these lines

Comment: in your answer, you mentioned `helpers/terminal-reporter.js`. How can I let `jasmine` know and use this file, not others?

Comment: oh. I think that i figured thing out. `.js` file could be any file. The only need is to execute `node` with that file. There is no need for `jasmine` cli, but `jasmine` local node is required.

Helper files path is defined in the config object.

Thank you

Comment: jasmine-terminal-reporter seems also no more maintained.

Comment: I had to do `jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);` in Jasmine 3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a relatively old question but found something which worked for me

```
describe('Desc1',() => {
   
    afterEach(() => {
      const myReporter = {
        specDone: (result) => {
          console.log('Spec FullName: ' + result.fullName);
          console.log('Spec Result: ' + result.status);
        }
      };
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(myReporter);
    });
})
```

Credit for the solution : https://groups.google.com/g/jasmine-js/c/qqOk6Nh7m4c/m/Nyovy2EjAgAJ

Comment: Works well, though you can paste the new reporter a setup.js helper rather than an aftereach (which might add it a bunch of times)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter).

Just add at the top of your test file:

```
import { SpecReporter } from 'jasmine-spec-reporter';
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: 'pretty' } }));
```